# Kotlin: Returning an object from a fold closure

Tags: kotlin, fold

I am building my first Kotlin Multiplatform app, I have not done Kotlin for a long time.  The library I am using uses Folds (Aws Cognito: https://github.com/Liftric/cognito-idp)

I am trying to get the function below to return a **User object** however I am obviously missing how to use the fold()

```
    suspend fun getUser(accessToken: String) : User {
            
            provider.getUser(accessToken ).fold(
                onSuccess = {
                    print("login")
                    currentUser = User.populateUserDetails(it)

                   // Here is the error
                   return@fold currentUser
                },
                onFailure = {
                    // Handle exceptions
                    print(it.message)
                }
            )
        }
```

> Type mismatch. Required:Unit. Found:User

How can I adjust the code above to return a **User Object** instead of a Unit object.

The framework uses folds everywhere which seems pointless if you can not return the data you requested.

Comment: For completeness of the question, please indicate the return type of `provider.getUser(accessToken)`. Basically explain which `fold()` function you are using. AFAIU, the type seems to be `kotlin.Result` and thus fold is https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/fold.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be the documentation of [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/fold.html):

> Returns the result of onSuccess for the encapsulated value if this instance represents success or the result of onFailure function for the encapsulated Throwable exception if it is failure.

As you can see, `fold` itself returns a value, so you could return the whole expression by adding a `return` keyword in front:

```kotlin
return provider.getUser(accessToken).fold(...)
```

Now, in Kotlin, you don't need to use `return` within lambdas, as the last expression in the lambda is the value that is returned. Therefore, `onSuccess` could just be:

```kotlin
onSuccess = {
    print("login")
    User.populateUserDetails(it)
}
```

(unless you really want to have side effects, which you shouldn't)

So overall, you could write this:

```kotlin
suspend fun getUser(accessToken: String) : User {
    return provider.getUser(accessToken).fold(
        onSuccess = {
            print("login")
            User.populateUserDetails(it)
        },
        onFailure = {
            // Handle exceptions
            print(it.message)
        }
    )
}
```

But taking a step back, depending on what you want to do with the error case, there are plenty of other `Result` helpers you could use here. See the list here:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/

Comment: The `onFailure` lambda would also need to return a User for this code to work. Alternatively, it could return null if we change the return type to `User?`, but at that point `getOrNull()` would be simpler than `fold()`.

Comment: Oh right, for some reason I didn't pay much attention to the `onFailure` lambda. That's why I was mentioning that depending on what's actually done in the failure case, probably other helpers would fit better. Such as `getOrNull` or `getOrThrow`

Comment: This has the same issue thinking a Uint is returned Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit? but User? was expected

Comment: @Burf2000 the question is, what do you want to do in the failure case exactly?

Comment: The question is, how do I get it to compile returning a User Type? the code above you have pasted does not compile.  Failure is currently a Throwable

Comment: You can get it to compile in various ways, hence my question. If you want to return a user even in the failure case, then it works by adding that User to `onFailure`. If you want to throw, then use `getOrThrow` instead of `fold`. If you want to return null, then use `getOrNull`, or keep using fold but add `null` at the end of the lambda

Answer (score 0):

I am still baffled by this question however I believe the code below solves my issue.  It is linked to a comment mentioned.

All I wanted to do is return the gathered data or throw if it fails.

suspend fun getUser(accessToken: String) : User? {

```
val user = provider.getUser(accessToken).getOrThrow()
return User.populateUserDetails(user)
```

}